# Non UI reports in Jmeter xml format is unreadable

Tags: xml, csv, jmeter

I am facing a problem in jmeter reports.
I want to run my test plan as nightly, and to see it's results.
I also want to display the sampler response message (so it means I must use format XML, since in property file mentioned this is only supported for XML).
The problem is that the report is not readable like CSV, can not perform sorting or anything else.
If I run it manually via UI and put simple Data writer it works OK with CSV, however if I use it in Non UI must use the XML file.
Provided CSV that I run manually and the xml file from Non UI.
Is their any way the display it better? maybe in HTML format? 
for Now I need to select between two options
1. readable format (CSV) without all the data (response message)
2. Unreadable format (XML) with all the data that I need

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Results file configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# This section helps determine how result data will be saved.
# The commented out values are the defaults.

# legitimate values: xml, csv, db.  Only xml and csv are currently supported.
#jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv


# true when field should be saved; false otherwise

# assertion_results_failure_message only affects CSV output
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
#
# legitimate values: none, first, all
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all
#
#jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
# response_data is not currently supported for CSV output
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
# Save ResponseData for failed samples
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=false
# Only available with HttpClient4
#jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=false
# Only available with HttpClient4
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false

# Timestamp format - this only affects CSV output files
# legitimate values: none, ms, or a format suitable for SimpleDateFormat
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

# For use with Comma-separated value (CSV) files or other formats
# where the fields' values are separated by specified delimiters.
# Default:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=,
# For TAB, since JMeter 2.3 one can use:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=\t

# Only applies to CSV format files:
# Print field names as first line in CSV
#jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true

# Optional list of JMeter variable names whose values are to be saved in the result data files.
# Use commas to separate the names. For example:
#sample_variables=SESSION_ID,REFERENCE
# N.B. The current implementation saves the values in XML as attributes,
# so the names must be valid XML names.
# Versions of JMeter after 2.3.2 send the variable to all servers
# to ensure that the correct data is available at the client.

# Optional xml processing instruction for line 2 of the file:
# Example:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../extras/jmeter-results-detail-report.xsl"?>
# Default value:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=

# Prefix used to identify filenames that are relative to the current base
#jmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix=~/

# AutoFlush on each line written in XML or CSV output
# Setting this to true will result in less test results data loss in case of Crash
# but with impact on performances, particularly for intensive tests (low or no pauses)
# Since JMeter 2.10, this is false by default
#jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=false
```

Provided a pic
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default [JMeter result save configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) in order to generate CSV output.

**In addition** you can add i.e. [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to save full request and response data into a **separate** file (which you can specify via the "Filename" input)

[image: JMeter View Results Tree]

Once your test is finished you will get 2 result files:

1. csv file with baseline metrics
2. xml file with full request and response details.

Be aware that storing request and response data will create massive IO overhead and might have negative impact on your test when it comes to high loads so once you will be happy with your script behavior turn off this View Results Tree listener and configure JMeter to store only those metrics which are absolutely required. Ideally [you should be running your test with all the listeners disabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing).

Comment: Dimity I am still not understand, if I run jmeter from the command line, I need to configure the report in the UI like your pic? moreover I marked to save the request + response but it is not displayed in CSV?   here is my property configuration, and in the CSV I still see connect \ idleTime \ Latency \ allThreads \ grpthreads \ sentBytes\Bytes . how can I remove them from CSV

Answer (score 0):

Response message is saved to CSV format, same for the yellow field you show.

So you should be able to use Web Report:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Comment: but mentioned "response_data is not currently supported for CSV output" what is the difference?

Comment: In your question, you mentioned response message

Comment: yeah I just not understand the difference I thought it is the same thing